# Performing casting for present value formula

Tags: c#, casting

I am trying to do the present value calculator for my school but I am stuck in the part where I have to perform "casting".

I was instructed to use 3 decimals (payment, growth, rate) and 1 integer (year).

The formula I am following is:
[image]

```
decimal payment, growth, rate, presentValue;
int years;
presentValue = payment /(rate - growth)* 1 - Math.Pow(1 + growth / 1 + rate, years);
presentValueLabel.Text = presentValue.ToString("n3");
```

I tried to use `(decimal)years` and `decimal.Parse(years)` but none worked.

Comment: Hi Maximilious, welcome to stack overflow! Next time please consider using code indentation (4 spaces at the start of the line, or highlight the code and pressing ctrl-k) instead of using <code> tags for blocks of code - makes it a look a lot nicer and provides syntax highlighting.

Comment: thanks for the heads up!

Comment: `presentValue = payment / (rate - growth) * (decimal)(1 - Math.Pow((double)(1 + growth) / (double)(1 + rate), years));`

Answer (score 0):

You should implement the calculation correctly to start of with. It would be properly implemented thus:

```
presentValue = payment /(rate - growth)
        * (1 - Math.Pow((1 + growth) / (1 + rate), years));
```

Then having done that, you can start doing some casting, as the `Math.Pow(double, double)` takes two arguments that are both double and not decimal:

```
presentValue = payment /(rate - growth)
        * (1 - Math.Pow((1 + (double) growth) / (1 + (double) rate), (double) years));
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to provide *explicit casting* between `double` and `decimal` (and vice-versa).

Here's an example

```
presentValue = (decimal)((double)(payment / (rate - growth) * 1) - 
                               Math.Pow((double)(1 + growth / 1 + rate), (double) years));
```

That's really messy though, and doesn't really make sense to do it this way. Perhaps you're allowed to use `double` instead (I suppose the hint to use a `decimal` was that you want a number with decimal places). If you change it to double, you get:

```
double payment, growth, rate, presentValue;
int years;
presentValue = payment /(rate - growth)* 1 - Math.Pow(1 + growth / 1 + rate, years);
```

Which works perfectly (assuming you give values to these 4 variables).

Answer (score 0):

Try below,

```
Convert.ToDecimal(years)
```

Also, try using brackets to group together the related operations. Otherwise, .Net follows its operator precedence rules. See [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx)

For example,

```
Math.Pow(1 + growth / 1 + rate, years)
```

should be written as,

```
Math.Pow((1 + growth) / (1 + rate), years)
```